# Magento1.9 - List of all in stock product brands to main menu

Tags: magento-1.9, products, menu

I have listed all brands to the main menu using below code and it gives all available brands.

```
$attributeId = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getIdByCode('catalog_product','brand');
$attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attributeId);
$attributeOptions = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
```

But, now I wants to load only brands, which related products are is in stock(`qty>=1`) to the Main Menu.

So How could I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are requesting is not that simple or 2-3 lines of code.

Here is the dazzy way to achieve this

- Load class Magento/CatalogSearch/Model/Layer
- method getProductCollection()
- than get attributes from this collection
- get your brand attribute model and its options

In this way all primary checks like enable/ disable, stock will be taken care of

Comment: Thank you for your answer Yash. But I did'n get it. It will grateful if you could describe more about your answer please. Because , I'm new to magento & back-end development. I have tried like this ; but it doesn't give "brand".[$_productCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('size','name','brand'))
    ->joinField(
        'qty',
        'cataloginventory/stock_item',
        'qty',
        'product_id=entity_id',
        '{{table}}.is_in_stock=1',
        'left')
        ->addAttributeToFilter('qty', array('gt' => 1));]